# How to share service application between Sharepoint 2013 and 2010

Tags: search, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, service-application

I'm trying to publish the search service application from my Sharepoint 2013 farm and have the Sharepoint 2010 farm consume it. Ive followed these steps from the Technet site and I am stuck at step 6:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff621100.aspx

If you click the link in step 6 and scroll down, you see the first shell command:

```
Set-SPAuthenticationRealm -realm <RealmName>
```

This command apparently doesn't exist in SP 2010. The command doesn't exist. Is there a way around this or any other different steps that someone knows about to finish up this connection? I'm almost done I just need this last step (6).
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. Step 6 is not required. Just make sure to set the Connection to the new search service as the default instead of having the original service as the default.

To set it as default, navigate to Central Admin, Application Management, Configure service application associations and for the Web Applications View, select "default" (or your Application Proxy Group name) and then you should get an option to set the new search as the default. Be aware that any Scopes you have may not work if they weren't upgraded.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to set the default search service? Thanks.